# grep -o -f invalid regular expression error

Tags: grep

I am trying to count the number of words in a huge file based on a list of words provided by another file.

`grep -F -f matchingwords.txt bigfile.txt` works. But I need the count for each word in `matchingwords.txt`.

I tried `grep -o -f matchingwords.txt bigfile.txt`, it threw an error invalid regular expression error

```
while read line; do grep -o "$line" bigfile.txt; done < matchingwords.txt > output.txt
```

But I am not sure how to get the count from above

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `-o` with `-F`? It sounds like otherwise there's something in `matchingwords.txt` that is interpreted as a malformed regex...and it doesn't sound like your intention is to use regexes.

So assuming you get that figured out here's one way to count the occurrences of matches for each of the words:

```
grep -F -o -f matchingwords.txt bigfile.txt | sort | uniq --count
```

You'll get something along these lines:

```
 5 apple
12 banana
 9 orange
```